# Removing the beginner "create this file" links from GitLab repository page

Tags: gitlab-ce

Our customer/partner is using GitLab 15.10.1 community edition.  Repository pages are displayed with this giant wodge of dashed border "buttons" in the middle:

[image]

Mousing over them it's obvious that they're shortcuts for quickly creating files with common names, or links to the configuration pages for other GitLab features.  But some of the projects have multiple lines of these dumb things, and in certain browser sizes they take up a ridiculous amount of space.  We're never going to use these.

How do we get rid of them?  (Searching GitLab's docs was useless.  Googling for "gitlab dashed buttons on repository" along with the exact text of the links found the file in GitLab source code that registers the button links for i14n, but nothing about how to remove the damn things.  Nothing under repo config, project config, webhooks, or integration even mentions them.)